# MySQL Ratings From Two Tables

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL and PHP to build a data layer for a flash game. Retrieving lists of levels is pretty easy, but I've hit a roadblock in trying to fetch the level's average rating along with it's pointer information. Here is an example data set:

levels Table:

```
level_id | level_name
       1 | Some Level
       2 | Second Level
       3 | Third Level
```

ratings Table:

```
rating_id | level_id | rating_value
        1 |    1     |      3
        2 |    1     |      4
        3 |    1     |      1
        4 |    2     |      3
        5 |    2     |      4
        6 |    2     |      1
        7 |    3     |      3
        8 |    3     |      4
        9 |    3     |      1
```

I know this requires a join, but I cannot figure out how to get the average rating value based on the level_id when I request a list of levels. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT levels.level_id, AVG(ratings.level_rating WHERE levels.level_id = ratings.level_id) FROM levels
```

I know my SQL is flawed there, but I can't figure out how to get this concept across. The only thing I can get to work is returning a single average from the entire ratings table, which is not very useful.

Ideal Output from the above conceptually valid but syntactically awry query would be:

```
level_id | level_rating
        1| 3.34
        2| 1.00
        3| 4.54
```

My main issue is I can't figure out how to use the level_id of each response row before the query has been returned. It's like I want to use a placeholder... or an alias... I really don't know and it's very frustrating. The solution I have in place now is an EPIC band-aid and will only cause me problems long term... please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `levels` table is `InnoDB`:

```
SELECT  l.level_id, COALESCE(AVG(level_rating), 0)
FROM    levels l
LEFT JOIN
        ratings r
GROUP BY
        l.id
```

If your `levels` table is `MyISAM`:

```
SELECT  l.level_id,
        (
        SELECT  COALESCE(AVG(level_rating), 0)
        FROM    rating r
        WHERE   r.level_id = l.level_id
        )
FROM    levels l
```

Subquery is more efficient for `MyISAM`, since it's heap-based and `GROUP BY` would require sorting and/or materialization.

Comment: Apparently my tables are MyISAM... your second query works great. I was able to cut out a ton of unncessary code that combines two arrays from two seperate queries into one!

I also see how you alias (is this the proper term?) the table names... that abstraction makes a lot of sense and I can see using that in the future as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `GROUP BY` clause. Try this:

```
SELECT   levels.level_id
       , AVG(ratings.level_rating)
FROM     levels
JOIN     ratings ON levels.level_id = ratings.level_id
GROUP BY levels.level_id
```

When you use an aggregate function (AVG, SUM, COUNT, MIN, MAX), you need to group your query by the other attributes you are selecting. This is why `SELECT AVG(ratings.level_rating)` works without a `GROUP BY`, but trying to select the level_id as well requires the group by.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT level_id, AVG(ratings.level_rating)
FROM levels JOIN ratings USING(level_id)
GROUP BY level_id
```

Note that `level_id` is never referenced to a specific table, as it's used in the `USING` part of the join

Comment: I did not know about the `USING` command.  Now I want back the hours of my life I've spent typing out PK/FK joins the long way.

Comment: @keithjgrant I know what you mean. if you want even shorter, try `NATURAL JOIN`, though I've had some rather unexpected results. Also, if you need to reference a particular table's column (often in subqueries) you'll have to revert every reference of that name to an `ON` since `USING` makes it table-less, for want of a better word